# Problem with Firebase migration to androidX

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, androidx

- Android Studio version: 3.4.1
- Firebase Component: firebase-messaging:
- Component version: 17.3.2

Hi Guys, 
I have a problem with migration my application which is using firebase messaging to androidx.
I followed the instructions https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Unfortunately it looks like the firebase components were not migrated yet

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<clinit>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:101)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:244)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:53)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1927)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1902)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:47)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6578)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6133)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6043)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList
```

Is there any workaround for this ?
I thought that somehow magically it will be resolved by adding:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Anyway.. I have no clue (as FirebaseApp is still holding the old dependency to v4 support library).
Am I missing something ? 
Thanks for any help.

build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode project.sdkVersionCode
        versionName project.sdkVersionName

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

configurations.all { exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'}
configurations.all { exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-compat'}
configurations.all { exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:17.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.58.0.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.15.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Show your build.gradle, btw better to use refactor, IDE will migrate your project to AndroidX automatically

Comment: @user1209216  I've updated the initial question with build.gradle contents.

Comment: I'm not sure what causes your problem. I'd suggest to revert your changes and try automatic migration - Refactor->Migrate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56730155/7254873

Answer (score 2):

I found a problem, the solution was to update build gradle version to at least 3.2.0. This is also what automatic migration through android studio says "*upgrade build gradle plugin to at least 3.2.0*"

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
```

However from the implementation point of view it is very strange... and people easily can be confused...

If the plugin version < 3.2.0 then the old ArrayMap from v4 support is downloaded and placed in cache in FirebaseApp class.

In case > 3.2.0 the ArrayMap from androidx packages are taken.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the AndroidX Collections library which now host that file:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/collection/ArrayMap.html

```
implementation 'androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0'
```

Comment: I tried also to add collection dependency from androidx but without success. FirebaseApp (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-common/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp.java) is bounded with ArrayMap from android.support.v4.util package.

Comment: Libraries usually handle that internally. What about these: `configurations.all { exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'}` did you try removing those?

Comment: Yes this actually helped me to get rid of all dependencies to support-v4 library.