# Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

Tags: android

I was working on an Android Studio application when I ran into this error.

```
    Process: com.example.visualizercopy, PID: 28098
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.visualizercopy/io.esense.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2812)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.visualizercopy-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.visualizercopy-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.visualizercopy-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.visualizercopy-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.visualizercopy-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.visualizercopy-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.visualizercopy-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.visualizercopy-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.visualizercopy-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.visualizercopy-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.visualizercopy-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.visualizercopy-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.visualizercopy-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:424)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2471)
        at io.esense.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6757)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2704)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2812)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6317)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
2019-06-23 16:25:42.234 28098-28098/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

This is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.visualizercopy"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

This is the constraint layout tag in my xml file

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/PLAY_PARENT"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">
```

I have looked into my error on this site and google, and the common answer is to add `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`, however compile is now obsolete, and when I replace compile with implementation and changed it to the newest version (`'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta1'`) I still run into the same error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to update the `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` tags to `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` in my layout XML.

Answer (score 1):

You are using androidX packages. So you have to migrate all android.support library with androidX.

So replace below line in gradle,

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta1'
```

With this,

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
```

Reference [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `androidX` packages or you want to use them for your project, then you have to migrate your project to `androidX`. For  that you need to follow below steps:

1) In Android Studio, just goto **`Refactor-> Migrate to AndroidX`** to migrate your project and there you can backup your project if some problem occurs migrating project.

After that your `dependendencies` will have `androidX` packages automatically.

Further reading: [Here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)