# How to find which library use AndroidX

Tags: android, react-native, androidx

I'm using react native and my Android project isn't compiling anymore because of this error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:28:5-109:19 to override.
```

I've tried to add that tag but I'm getting always errors!!
I've tried to remove all packages to find which had androidX support or how to fix this bug, but I've been stuck for days!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in your log?

Comment: Are you using the latest firebase or google play services libraries?

Comment: Google play services 16.1 is one possible cause which I experienced recently.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56730155/7254873

Comment: do you have these two properties in your gradle.properties? android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to a Google update on the google place services. You can find which library is using AndroidX with this command:

```
gradlew app:dependencies
```

App is the name of your module/project but that is usually the default one.

If you can't solve this this way, post your project and app build.gradle

Comment: I've tried with "./gradelw androidDependencies" and it works!

Comment: Ah right, you are un *NIX. Please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you import the right version for AndroidX from here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

I got stuck one day also just because integrate wrong version. So check it just to be sure.