# YoutubeAndroidPlayerAPI error after migrating to AndroidX in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-youtube-api, androidx

I have android native project (java) with YoutubeAndroidPlayerAPI.jar official library version 1.2.2 that have a function to be embedded Youtube Player in my App. Anything work fine before migrating to AndroidX.

I realized that the code inside the YoutubeAndroidPlayerAPI didn't support to AndroidX. The class of YoutubePlayerSupportFragment that extends to Fragment still use import android.support.v4.app.Fragment not androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.

i Can not edit the code of YoutubeAndroidPlayerAPI (read-only mode) for migrating to AndroidX.

This is my sample code of my project that getting error and red color warning at 'setArguments', 'getArguments' and 'getActivity'.

```
public class FragmentVideoPlayer extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

private YouTubePlayer player;
public FragmentVideoPlayer() {
    }

public static FragmentVideoPlayer newInstance(final String videoId) {
        final FragmentVideoPlayer youTubeFragment = new FragmentVideoPlayer();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(KEY_VIDEO_ID, videoId);
        youTubeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return youTubeFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        final Bundle arguments = getArguments();

        if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey(KEY_VIDEO_ID)) {
            mVideoId = bundle.getString(KEY_VIDEO_ID);
        } else if (arguments != null && arguments.containsKey(KEY_VIDEO_ID)) {
            mVideoId = arguments.getString(KEY_VIDEO_ID);
        }

        String API_KEY = new SharedPref(getActivity()).getYoutubeApiKey();
        initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }
}
```

And this is some code from YoutubeAndroidPlayerAPI

```
    package com.google.android.youtube.player;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.b;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ab;

public class YouTubePlayerSupportFragment extends Fragment implements Provider {
    private final YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.a a = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.a((byte)0);
    private Bundle b;
    private YouTubePlayerView c;
    private String d;
    private OnInitializedListener e;
    private boolean f;
}
```

Please, help me to solve this problem. How to fix YoutubeAndroidPlayerAPI jar file to supporting AndroidX?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56730155/7254873

Comment: I already migrate via refactoring to AndroidX in Android Studio. And fix the problem manually one by one at some import such as fragment, etc. But, i have a problem to change the import code in fragment inside YoutubeAndroidPlayerAPI in Jar file that has read-only mode.

Comment: @zebhi have u found a solution to this?

Comment: Not yet. I just submit a bugs report to Google Team a couple days ago. And the progress is still in review.
There are peoples that have same problem too.

Comment: I'm just starting a new personal project and I'm already facing this kind of issue..

Comment: @zebhi Did you figure it out? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube has not updated player library. You can use android-youtube-player 
https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player
It is very similar to native player. It uses webview and iframe to player video. It provides customizable player controlls.

Comment: The last time they updated it was 6 years ago and I have a feeling that they won't be doing any more updates.