# Getting errors trying to build a github project

Tags: android, android-design-library

I'm new in android studio

i'm struggling to build this project

https://github.com/CodingInfinite/AndroidLoginScreen

I'm getting many errors that i fixed but still that app won't run

it open and crash

this is the errors

> 07-07 00:06:02.063 8601-8601/com.example.testdesign E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.testdesign, PID: 8601
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testdesign/com.example.testdesign.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>           at com.example.testdesign.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #78: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>           at com.example.testdesign.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.testdesign-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.testdesign-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.testdesign-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.testdesign-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.testdesign-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.testdesign-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.testdesign-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.testdesign-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.testdesign-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.testdesign-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.testdesign-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.testdesign-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.testdesign-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:583)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)

so apparently the error is here

[image]

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.testdesign;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;



import static android.view.View.GONE;
import static android.view.View.VISIBLE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView bookIconImageView;
    private TextView bookITextView;
    private ProgressBar loadingProgressBar;
    private RelativeLayout rootView, afterAnimationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
        new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                bookITextView.setVisibility(GONE);
                loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
                rootView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorSplashText));
                bookIconImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_color_book);
                startAnimation();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        bookIconImageView = findViewById(R.id.bookIconImageView);
        bookITextView = findViewById(R.id.bookITextView);
        loadingProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.loadingProgressBar);
        rootView = findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        afterAnimationView = findViewById(R.id.afterAnimationView);
    }

    private void startAnimation() {
        ViewPropertyAnimator viewPropertyAnimator = bookIconImageView.animate();
        viewPropertyAnimator.x(50f);
        viewPropertyAnimator.y(100f);
        viewPropertyAnimator.setDuration(1000);
        viewPropertyAnimator.setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                afterAnimationView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

main_activity.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bookIconImageView"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/white_book_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bookITextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bookIconImageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/booki"
        android:textColor="@color/colorSplashText"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loadingProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ProgressBarStyle" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/afterAnimationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/WelcomeTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/welcome_back"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/readItTogetherTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/WelcomeTextView"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/read_it_together"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/readItTogetherTextView"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextView"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextView"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/sign_up"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextView"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/forget_password"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextView"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/skipTextView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_drawable"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/skipTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="@string/skip"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextView"
            android:textSize="15sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

build.gradle (app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testdesign"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

}
```

**API 23**

**ANDROID STUDIO 3.4.1**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56730155/7254873

Comment: @SumitShukla still the splash screen that need to show for 5seconds didn't show
check my project **https://www.mediafire.com/file/739clslcs190ol5/testDesign.zip/file**

Comment: Check your logcat for errors.

Comment: @SumitShukla checked, i got **07-07 03:39:43.708 11597-11636/com.example.testdesign E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf

07-07 03:39:43.709 11597-11636/com.example.testdesign E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change CountDownTimer to

```
  new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            bookITextView.setVisibility(GONE);
            loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            bookIconImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_book_icon);
            rootView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorBackground));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            bookIconImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.background_color_book);
            rootView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorSplashText));
            loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
            startAnimation();

        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you have the dependency for the `TextInputEditText`. Add this to your build.gradle(app) under dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Next, Change your import for AppCompatActivity to:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Lastly, add the following to all your views that are in the `initViews` method. Put the word `this` in front of all the `findViewById()` calls. They should look like the following:

```
private void initViews() {
  bookIconImageView = this.findViewById(R.id.bookIconImageView);
  bookITextView = this.findViewById(R.id.bookITextView);
  loadingProgressBar = this.findViewById(R.id.loadingProgressBar);
  rootView = this.findViewById(R.id.rootView);
  afterAnimationView = this.findViewById(R.id.afterAnimationView);
}
```

Hope this works for you! This got it running on my end.

**Update:**

This is the build.gradle(app) from my app that I was able to get running.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I cannot use import `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`

It show an error at v7

Comment: add this to your gradle(app) dependencies. 
        `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` The 28 is the target sdk version that is in my project that I am working in. It will probably prompt you to change it to match your target sdk.

Comment: yes i can't use `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;`
and `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'` it always change to import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
and     `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'`

Comment: can you upload your the project  and send it to me to check maybe i missed something

Comment: Update your post with the gradle(app) code from your project.

Comment: Didn't worked, but i changed `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText` to  `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText` and the app opened but without the first loading screen, open directly to login page, and logo move a little bit, i think there's same change happen to class animator or design, can you please check the update .java and xml codes, thanks