# What is androidx version of library for Media Style NotificationCompact?

Tags: android, android-notifications, media

I have to create Media Notifications, What is the equivalent androidx library to `implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'` support library?

I used the following androidx library but ended with an error...

```
implementation 'androidx.android.support.v4.media.app'
```

> ERROR: Supplied String module notation
>   'androidx.android.support.v4.media.app' is invalid. Example notations:
>   'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2',
>   'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56730155/7254873

Answer (score 1):

Use `androidx.media:media:1.0.0`

To get all dpendencies of android X use the below link
[Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)